# Laravel where not

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to replicate this query with Eloquent QueryBuilder:

```
select * from table_name
where type = 'custom_type' 
and not
(
(topable_type = 'Car' and topable_id = 1)
or 
(topable_type = 'Car' and topable_id = 2)
)
```

The problem comes with the `and not` part. As far as I can see Laravel does not support "whereNot" functionality.

Edit: Code attempt:

```php
$deleteQuery = Item::where('type', '=', $type);
foreach ($except as $exceptItem) {
  $deleteQuery = $deleteQuery->where(fn($query) => $query->where('topable_type', '!=', $exceptItem->type)->where('topable_id', '!=', $exceptItem->id));
}
$deleteQuery->delete();
```

Edit2: With Tim Lewis'es help I modified my previous attempt and it's working now:

```
$deleteQuery = Item::where('type', $type);

foreach ($except as $exceptItem) {
    $deleteQuery = $deleteQuery->where(fn($query) => $query->where('topable_type', $topableItem->type)->where('topable_id', $topableItem->id)
            , null, null, 'and not');
}
        
$deleteQuery->delete();
```

It doesn't generate exact query as I mentioned above, but pretty similair and it works as expected.

Comment: can you mention eloquent query which you have tried

Comment: Check this thread on the official Laravel GitHub page: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/708. There's an external package available, or you can add `and not` as the 4th param to any `where()` clause.

Comment: @JohnLobo I tried different approach with eloquent, and it doesn't work: $deleteQuery = Item::where('type', '=', $type);
foreach ($except as $exceptItem) {
$deleteQuery = $deleteQuery->where(fn($query) => $query->where('topable_type', '!=', $exceptItem->type)->where('topable_id', '!=', $exceptItem->id)
);
}
$deleteQuery->delete();

Comment: @walemy Next time, [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68226172/edit), don't post code in the comments, it's hard to read. (I did this for you this time)

Comment: You can use whereRaw() for the conditions in laravel

Comment: @walemy Another thing, don't add your solution to your question... Add an answer below with your modified code if it works and solves your issue. Stackoverflow is a Q&A (Question and Answer) site, please use it properly by adding an answer to your question in the proper section, not having the answer in your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  do chained where condition

```
Item::where('type','custom_type')->where(function ($query){
      $query->where(function ($query){
          $query->where('topable_type','Car');
          $query->where('topable_id',1);
      });

        $query->orwhere(function ($query){
            $query->where('topable_type','Car');
            $query->where('topable_id',2);
        });
    },null, null, 'and not')->get();
```

Ref:https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/708